# java.util.NoSuchElementException on reading a file (Scanner)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a text file with 3 words on it, and on trying to read these words I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException  
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)  
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)  
    at search.search(search.java:121)  
    at main.main(main.java:38)
```

Below is the code in question:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(path + client + "\\" + cat +"\\" + query + ".arch");  
while (reader.hasNext()){  
    String a = reader.next();  // line 121
    String b = reader.next();  
    String c = reader.next();  
    file = new File (path + client + "\\" + a +"\\" + b + ".arch");  
    print(file);  
}
```

Below are the contents of the file:

> po ref refc (with a new line at the end)

What gives?
I've used a very similar system before, with the same file, and everything worked, I even use a very similar system some lines below.
Btw the String c is not yet implemented but shall be further down.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure line 121 is not one of the next lines?

You check `reader.hasNext()` to make sure there is another entry, but you then read 3 entries in `a`, `b`, `c`. If there is only one for example, `b = reader.next()` would fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply;  I managed to fix it by changing the scanner to Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(path + client + "\\" + cat +"\\" + querry + ".arch"));