# Java Exception in thread “main” java.util.NoSuchElementException - Using scanner to read files

Tags: java

I already searched the various topic's about the subject, but couldn't find anyone in the same situation or any solution that i could use so far.

I just want to read a txt file in the format :
Double0 Double0 Int0
Double1 Double1 Int1
..
Doublen Doublen Intn

And here is my code:

```
public void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    try {               
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
            String line = br.readLine();
            Scanner trainFile = null;
            while (line != null) {      
                line.trim();
                trainFile = new Scanner(line);
                double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
                double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
                int type = trainFile.nextInt();
                this.database.add(new Point(x,y,type));
                line = br.readLine();
            }   
            trainFile.close();
            br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The funny thing is that this function worked for a while, but when i populated the txt file with more data it stopped working. I also checked the file for eventual mistakes but everything is fine. According to my stacktrace, the bug appears at the first NextDouble() call. Does anyone have an a idea?

update:

Here is the kind of file that is working:

```
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,9529350156283241  0,7383387609711926  2
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,9529350156283241  0,7383387609711926  2
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,48639272096486486 0,4378985495387871  1
```

But if I add some extra lines like this it stops working:

```
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,9529350156283241  0,7383387609711926  2
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,9529350156283241  0,7383387609711926  2
0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2
0,48639272096486486 0,4378985495387871  1
0,8632344357711337  0,5253407956535258  1
0,7351912765040557  0,8295830810436339  1
0,6369155743204543  0,2757349130759706  1
0,46512947234632146 0,4388586141249502  1
0,8677892876429869  0,599451235810409   1
0,8827084731154641  0,55652107505414    1
```

Comment: To help others to answer, you need to share your files also.

Comment: Most likely a problem with the structure of your input file. Check for incorrect new line character or share the file contents

Comment: Another extra info:
I have the following file:
    0,6580097206539348 0,36101701387184226 2
    0,9529350156283241 0,7383387609711926 2
    0,6580097206539348 0,36101701387184226 2
    0,9529350156283241 0,7383387609711926 2
    0,6580097206539348 0,36101701387184226 2
    0,48639272096486486 0,4378985495387871 1

and my code works,
When I add the following new line at the eof 

0,8632344357711337 0,5253407956535258 1


It throws the error.

Comment: add it to your question plz

Comment: what do you mean your code works?

Comment: `0,6580097206539348` is not formatted properly to be parsed as a double. Replace the commas with dots and it'll work.

Comment: If i replace , for . it does not work alfasin.

Comment: @DanielVilas-Boas weird, cause it works for me. Add a debug-print after you trim the line and see where exactly does it fail

Comment: I mean that my code works for some inputs and for others it doesn't Kick Buttowski. Read my comment above with the explanation

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.util.NoSuchElementException on reading a file (Scanner)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11602492/java-util-nosuchelementexception-on-reading-a-file-scanner)

Comment: @alfasin, Adding a print statement after triming the line i've got 8 lines out of 12 from the file printed correctly and the error.

Comment: @DanielVilas-Boas post the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next input should *always* be a double, right?  So instead of `while(line != null)` (which will return true when you have an empty line) check `while(scanner.hasNextDouble())`:

```
public void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    try {               
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
        final Scanner trainFile = new Scanner(br);
        while (trainFile.hasNextDouble()) {      
            double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
            double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
            int type = trainFile.nextInt();
            this.database.add(new Point(x,y,type));
        }   
        trainFile.close();
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You still need to change the comma to a decimal point.  Otherwise the above will not work.

If your file has commas and you need to interpret it as a decimal point then you can try the following:

```
public void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException{    
    try {               
        final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            line = line.replace(',', '.');
            final Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
            if(!scanner.hasNextDouble())
                break;// quit loop
            // else continue loop
            double x = lineScanner.nextDouble();
            double y = lineScanner.nextDouble();
            int type = lineScanner.nextInt();
            this.database.add(new Point(x,y,type));
            line = br.readLine();
        }   
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the first code you posted was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand how you have your JRE setup so that it interprets a comma as a decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

> According to JavaDoc `nextDouble()` Scans the next **token** of the
>   input as a double.This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if
>   the next token cannot be translated into a valid double value.

So here `Scanner` is not able to find `Double` in your Line `0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2`.There is one solution is to just replace `,` with `.` during loop.
*(Only if your every line doesn't contain comma other than for this purpose)*

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
  String yourLine="0,6580097206539348  0,36101701387184226 2"
  Scanner trainFile = new Scanner(line.replace(',', '.'));
               double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
               double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
               int type = trainFile.nextInt();
```

---

Moreover for surviving from `Exception` you can use `hasNextDoubel()`,`hasNextInt()` method to make Scanner check whether there exist double/int in data,it returns `true/false`.You can read more about this at [#Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

In java, you cannot parse the doubles because of the comma in place of a decimal. Edit your file to use a period instead of a comma.

I tested the code by running the following function:

```
public static void readDatabase(String s) throws FileNotFoundException {

    File file = new File(s);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] values = line.split(" ");
        double x = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(values[1]);
        int type = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
        System.out.println(x + " : " + y + " : " + type);
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

On the file:

```
1.1 1.2 1 
2.1 2.2 2 
3.1 3.2 3
```

And got the result:

```
1.1 : 1.2 : 1
2.1 : 2.2 : 2
3.1 : 3.2 : 3
```

Note that my code separates the line based on spaces found, not using the scanner to search for doubles/ints. In flat files, it is better to use a standard for formatting (spaces, commas, colons, etc) rather than formatting the file, such that it is easier to parse the file down the road.

**EDIT**:

If you wish to keep your formatting of your flat file as it is, simply changing the commas to periods will solve your issue. I used your function (changing the database line to an output):

```
public static void readDatabase(String s) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));
    String line = br.readLine();
    Scanner trainFile = null;
    while (line != null) {
        line.trim();
        trainFile = new Scanner(line);
        double x = trainFile.nextDouble();
        double y = trainFile.nextDouble();
        int type = trainFile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(x + " : " + y + " : " + type);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    trainFile.close();
    br.close();
}
```

On the file (this is the data you had given, with commas changed to periods):

```
0.6580097206539348  0.36101701387184226 2
0.9529350156283241  0.7383387609711926  2
0.6580097206539348  0.36101701387184226 2
0.9529350156283241  0.7383387609711926  2
0.6580097206539348  0.36101701387184226 2
0.48639272096486486 0.4378985495387871  1
0.8632344357711337  0.5253407956535258  1
0.7351912765040557  0.8295830810436339  1
0.6369155743204543  0.2757349130759706  1
0.46512947234632146 0.4388586141249502  1
0.8677892876429869  0.599451235810409   1
0.8827084731154641  0.55652107505414    1
```

And the output showed up fine.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for your help, but for a mysterous reason on my computer :

It does not work with dots, but when i change to commas it does read some lines 

The same code you said that was working there does not work here using the same file as ip.

Comment: Could you give me more information about your development environment? What compiler are you using, JDK version, what operating system are you using? Java is standalone, so it should work the same no matter the type of computer you are on. Also, did you try using my code and the file that I posted? That is a generic and basic example, like a proof of concept, then you can work up to the main file to see where the bug is.

Comment: Hey @Mike Elofson, using your code i managed to make it print correctly. But when i try to create a new Point inside the function to add to my database -> this.database.add(new Point(x,y,type)); after saving the 3 variables it says that i cannot use it in a static context. Do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put in a stack trace? What part cannot be used in a static context? If it is the readDatabase function itself, remove `static ` from the function definition. I need to know what can't be used in a static context, then I can most likely help you.

Comment: Using the same code you gave me and placing the new Point(x,y,type) instead of syso made eclipse point the error : cannot use it in a static context. I used another solution and it worked. Thanks for your help anyway!